# C++ AMP fft performance issue

Tags: c++, performance

I am writing code to take advantage of the fft library (http://ampfft.codeplex.com/) on C++ AMP. While it doesn give me siginifcant boost as compared to CPU implementations such as FFTW, I noticed that, if it is put in a **for** loop, the performances dramatically decreases as the loop iterates itself.

Here is the test code I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
transform.transform(in_GPU, out_GPU); 
}
std::cout << "time steps = " << iterations 
<< "\ttime taken for each steps = " 
<< (clock() - start) / float(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) / iterations  * 1000 
<< "ms"  << std::endl;
```

Here is the output:

```
   iterations   Time/iteration
   1000           1.001 ms
   2000           0.2925 ms
   5000           0.3248 ms
   10000          0.285 ms
   20000          0.3991 ms
   50000          0.4027 ms
   100000         0.4027 ms
   500000         0.4298 ms
```

I think the decrease in Time per iteration from 1000 to 2000 is due to the reduction in overhead. But that doesn't explain the increase from 10000 to 20000, or from 100000 to 500000.

So basically my program is running slower and slower in the ***for*** loop. Any idea? :)